# How can I filter child arrays in Gatsby GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, gatsby, sanity

This gets me all events with `showOnSite === true`:

```
query MyQuery {
  allSanityP2Event(filter: {showOnSite: {eq: true}}) {
    edges {
      node {
        showOnSite
        title
        relatedEvents {
          showOnSite
          title
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to then filter `relatedEvents` within those results, also by `showOnSite === true`. Surely GraphQL can do this?

Using `elemMatch` doesn't work as it gives me ONLY events where `relatedEvents` have `showOnSite === true`, like this:

```
query MyQuery {
  allSanityP2Event(filter: {showOnSite: {eq: true}, relatedEvents: {elemMatch: {showOnSite: {eq: true}}}}) {
    edges {
      node {
        showOnSite
        title
        relatedEvents {
          showOnSite
          title
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Logically, I'd expect this to work, but no...

```
query MyQuery {
  allSanityP2Event(filter: {showOnSite: {eq: true}}) {
    edges {
      node {
        showOnSite
        title
        relatedEvents(filter: {showOnSite: {eq: true}}) {
          showOnSite
          title
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well that's that one solved. Turns out it's Sanity's fault.

[image]